# Venv interpreter is faster than system interpreter?? Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-venv

I have been developing a Pacman game in python using pygame module, using IDE Pycharm. When setting up my project I went with the default settings in Pycharm and it set up a venv for me. Running the code from my system interpreter makes it run really really slow with the cpu usage being more than 200%, while running with the venv interpreter it works as expected and cpu usage is about 70-80%. My question is why is that and how to fix it.

I have not uploaded my code, because I thought maybe the problem is not with the code, however if you want I will edit the post and upload the code as well.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: @Lagerbaer linux, in particular POP OS